# How to convert correct coordinates for Cesium?

Tags: geospatial, cesiumjs

I have the following coordinates:103.84958233542338,1.3669641300494784

I cannot tell if it's in the correct coordinates format for Cesium. It gives me a developer error "Cartesian is required." I have the following codes too.

```
  var storecoord=[103.84958233542338,1.3669641300494784];
  var splitcoord = storecoord.split(',');
  var pos = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(splitcoord[0],splitcoord[1]);
  var carto  = Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84.cartesianToCartographic(pos);
  var lon = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(carto.longitude);
  var lat = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(carto.latitude);
```

Any idea on any part that when wrong. I would like to use the variable lon & lat to create billboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've specified lon, lat in the correct order for `fromDegrees`.

Also, you can't call `.split` on an array, it's already split.  And it looks like you're converting from lon/lat to Cartesian3 and then back to lon/lat, is that just to verify the round-trip?

Anyway here's a [Sandcastle demo with a billboard](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=bZBdb4IwFIb/SsMVJqTAQIcOzRJ3abKLLbuRxRQ4smalh7QVo4v/fQX24Zw3J+fred/TtkwRbVBBgajK+ToMIprE03FyE0Xj2IbEC2k0mUwncRgFQTyNb5P49S6TmWwt2nLYgyJzImFPlqD5rqYvfc/NnKKvlygN4xJU5ox+OIHSQr/G66DT7CfM/J2EX269KgVpuOGgKStL9yOThDSobQfl7Nt/yZSxGZMR3SqsH6BSANq1ll6nPvI6KudC5MhUOSO9CiG8ZhXMSOZQ6ve59gfBzQor3GALSrADbWSVOb3EycbT6Py4I2L9jO7Fqd2K4zmpNgcBi8GMkHteN6gM2SnhWkcDdWOPs6b5rngHQwvdg91q6p+jaclbwsv5lf8lhWBa28l2J8QTP0LmLFLf7v9DBbKSy+pxeFS39hYuVkOTUpr6trxOGkSRM3Wh/Ak) at your lon/lat location:

```
var storecoord=[103.84958233542338,1.3669641300494784];

var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");

var lon = storecoord[0];
var lat = storecoord[1];

viewer.entities.add({
  position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(lon, lat),
  billboard: {
    image: "../images/Cesium_Logo_overlay.png",
  },
});

viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities);
```